# SCDF Set User Provided Environment Variables for the deployed stream app

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am deploying a stream on spring cloud dataflow version 2.1.2 on PCF. How do I pass "User Provided Environment Variables" to the deployed stream app.
Looks like all the properties I set are collapsed into the SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON. I have a requirement to keep them separate.

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override this using a CF deployer property `useSpringApplicationJson` to pass the application properties as environment properties instead of merging them into `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON`.

When deploying the stream, you can pass the Cloud Foundry deployer property `deployer.*.cloudfoundry.useSpringApplicationJson=false` to be applicable to all the applications inside the stream (using the wild card *).